# XPathQuery replace html string

Tags: ios, objective-c, xpathquery

I`m using XPathQuery lib to find nodes in a HTML Post from Wordpress, but I need to replace the found node in HTML, can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: interested in an answer as well